# Ingress-nginx on kubernetes with docker for windows and wsl2 gives "connection refused" on creation time

Tags: kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kind

### Install Ingress in Kind Cluster

```
~$ kubectl apply -f ingress-nginx.yaml
```

### Got

```
pod/foo-app created
service/foo-service created
pod/bar-app created
service/bar-service created
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress-nginx.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.100.173.14:443: connect: connection refused
```

### Tried this

```
~$ kubectl proxy
```

### Aiming for

Working Ingress with wsl 2.0

*Sources*:

- https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/examples/ingress/usage.yaml
- https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/ingress/

Comment: did you deploy the nginx ingress controller ?